# How to assign Unique int value to string or Char?

Tags: c, mapping

I want to assign integer value to character.Where 'C' has the least  and 'B' largest value.

Is there something better than mapping ?

For eg:-'C'=100,'D'=101,'E'=102....'B'=126.Is There any better way compared to mapping ?
If Input string is "BYE",Ouput should be 351 (Because 'B'=126,'Y'=123,E='102').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use designated array initializers:

```
// UCHAR_MAX is from header <limits.h>
int const map[UCHAR_MAX] = {
    ['C'] = 100,
    ['D'] = 101,
    ['B'] = 126,
};
```

Unassigned characters will have zero value.

You would then get single value with expression:

```
int value = map[(unsigned char)character];
```

Comment: Thanks alot i would try this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If ASCII coding doesn't meet your requirements, you must implement your own translating functions, for example:

```
struct TranslationMapRecord
{
   char character;
   int code;
};

struct TranslationMapRecord map[] =
{
 { 'C', 100 },
 { 'D', 101 },
...
 { 'B', 126 }
}

int translate(char c)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(map)/sizeof(map[0]); ++i)
  {
    if (map[i].character == c)
      return map[i].code;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot i was hoping such solution's .